# Add asterisks in block comments with vim

Tags: vim, editor, comments, customization, vi

How would I implement something where when I type

`/**<Return>`

It'll create

```
/**
 * |
```

Where the pipe == the cursor and as long as I keep making new lines of text and pressing enter it'll keep adding `*<Space>`s in.

And if I leave an empty line like:

```
/**
 * Foo bar baz...
 * <Return>
```

It'll close it like

```
/**
 * Foo bar baz...
 */
|
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior is dictated by `set formatoptions`, see `:help fo-table` for all the possible values for this option.

Verify your current setting with `:set fo?`. You want the letter `r` to be present. If it's not, execute `:set fo+=r` to add it.

Add `set formatoptions+=r` to your `~/.vimrc` to make the change stick between sessions.

Comment: Holy crap, didn't realize VIM had that built in. VIM has everything.